# when to use dot product and when to use the common product In neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, training, ai

I wanted to know when to use dot product and when to not , I also don't know when we must transpose an array and why should we , could someone help me to understand this ?
If you could give me the derivative of cost function with respect to each Weigh (W1, W2, W3) using notations bellow to compare it with the results I found I'll appreciate that !

[image: neural network]

Comment: To match the dimensions, we need to transform the arrays/weights accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Neuron-level operations:

First, let's describe the output of each neuron in the network **individually**.

**For the first hidden layer**:

$$ A_2^1 = f_2(Z_2^1) = f_2(X \cdot W_1^1)$$
$$ A_2^2 = f_2(Z_2^2) = f_2(X \cdot W_1^2)$$
$$ A_2^3 = f_2(Z_2^3) = f_2(X \cdot W_1^3)$$

Let me explain the notation a bit: $A_2^1$ is the output of the first neuron of the second layer. $f_2$ is the activation function of the second layer. $W_1^2$ is line connecting the second neuron of the weights you denote $W1$ in the figure.

**Second hidden layer**:

$$ A_3^1 = f_3(Z_3^1) = f_3(A_2^1 \cdot W_2^{11} + A_2^2 \cdot W_2^{21} +  A_2^3 \cdot W_2^{31})$$
$$ A_3^2 = f_3(Z_3^2) = f_3(A_2^1 \cdot W_2^{12} + A_2^2 \cdot W_2^{22} +  A_2^3 \cdot W_2^{32})$$
$$ A_3^3 = f_3(Z_3^3) = f_3(A_2^1 \cdot W_2^{13} + A_2^2 \cdot W_2^{23} +  A_2^3 \cdot W_2^{33})$$

Again $A_3^1$ is the output of the first neuron of the third layer and $f_3$ is the activation function of the the third layer. This time $W_2^{12}$ corresponds to the weight $W2$ that connects the first neuron of the previous layer to the second neuron of the current layer.

**For the output layer**:

$$ \hat y = A_4 = f_4(Z_4) = f_4(A_3^1 \cdot W_3^1 + A_3^2 \cdot W_3^2 + A_3^3 \cdot W_3^3)$$

The notation follows the rules above.

Note that all the above operations are between simple **numbers**, meaning that all $\cdot$ symbols you saw above are **common multiplications**! Because this way of representing Neural Networks isn't effective, instead of describing each neuron individually, we usually describe the operations of **layers** with vectors or arrays. This is where your question lies (about the dot product and the transposing).

## Layer-level operations:

**First hidden layer**:

$$ A_2 = f_2(Z_2) = f_2(X \cdot W_1) $$

In the above equation $W_1$, $Z_2$ and $A_2$ are all $1 \times 3$ arrays. While $X$ remains a simple number (you can think of it as a $1 \times 1$ array).

**Second hidden layer**:

$$ A_3 = f_3(Z_3) = f_3(A_2 \cdot W_2) $$

Again $A_3$, $Z_3$ and $A_2$ are $1 \times 3$ arrays. This time $W_2$ is a $3 \times 3$ array.

**Output layer**:

$$ A_4 = f_4(Z_4) = f_4(A_3 \cdot W_3) $$

Here, $A_4$ and $A_4$ are numbers and $W_3$ is a $3 \times 1$ array.

Every $\cdot$ in the above is a basic **matrix multiplication**. Because this example wasn't the best to answer your question, I'm going to change it a bit. Imagine if the second hidden layer had $4$ neurons instead of $3$. In order for us to get from a $1 \times 3$ array to a $1 \times 4$ one we would need a weight array with a shape of $3 \times 4$.

$$ 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  A_2^1 & A_2^2 & A_2^3
 \end{pmatrix}
\cdot
 \begin{pmatrix}
  W_2^{11} & W_2^{12} & W_2^{13} & W_2^{14}\\
  W_2^{21} & W_2^{22} & W_2^{23} & W_2^{24}\\
  W_2^{31} & W_2^{32} & W_2^{33} & W_2^{34}
 \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  Z_3^1 & Z_3^2 & Z_3^3 & Z_3^4
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

This is summarized as $A_2 \cdot W_2 = Z_3$. Because in matrix multiplication the order of the two matrices counts, we need to make sure that the operation is possible. If they are in a reverse order we need to **transpose** the weight array. This would result in the following equation: $W_2^T \cdot A_2 = Z_3$.